# why does the socket doesn't send the data and get stuck until the socket is stopped?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

i am trying to do a HTTP server implementation
EDIT 1: The project is for a high-school assignment. It doesn't meant to be a real implementation of an HTTP server .
the code is a bit messy so i will be doing my best to simplify. the overall idea of this project is that i send a HTTP request, and the server sends the response according to my request. I'm only allowed to send GET requests.

I have this simple function to check if an http request is valid by seeing the first element (which is supposed to be the type of request) and the third element which contains the http version. the function returns True and the URL if the request is valid, but if not, then returning False and the status code:

```
def validate_http_request(request):
    if len(request_split) >= 3:
        if request_split[2] == "HTTP/1.1":
            if request_split[0] == "GET":
                return True, request_split[1]
            else:
                return False, "405"
    return False, "400"
```

this function is working pretty well, returns what is supposed to..the real problem is this function which handles the client requests after establishing a connection:

```
def handle_client(client_socket):
    print('Client connected')

    while True:
        client_request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not client_request:
            break

        valid_http, resource = validate_http_request(client_request)
        if valid_http:
            print('Got a valid HTTP request')
            handle_client_request(resource, client_socket) #function that working well. sends to the client 200 or 404 response 
            break
        else:
            print('Got an invalid HTTP request')
            if resource == "405":
                http_response = "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed\nContent-Type: text/plain\nAllow: GET\n\n405 Method Not Allowed. Try another method!"
                #code stops here for some reason
                client_socket.send(http_response.encode())
            elif resource == "400":
                http_response = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n400 Bad Request"
                #code stops here for some reason
                client_socket.send(http_response.encode())

    print('Closing connection')
    client_socket.close()
```

if i send a GET request, even multiple time, working perfectly fine, until i send for example DELETE request. then the code freezes at the point i noted in the function above. when i stop the program, it finally sends it. why is that happening?

if someone wants to read the entire code, here it is:

```
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8080
DEFAULT_URL = "webroot/index.html"


def get_file_data(filename):
    try:
        filepath = f"webroot/{filename}"
        with open(filepath, "rb") as file:
            return file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None


def handle_client_request(resource, client_socket):
    url = resource if resource else DEFAULT_URL

    split_url = url.split('.')
    filetype = split_url[-1]
    if filetype == 'html':
        http_header = f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n"
    elif filetype == 'jpg':
        http_header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\n\n"
    else:
        http_header = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n"
        error_message = "404 Not Found\nThe requested resource could not be found."
        http_response = http_header + error_message
        client_socket.send(http_response.encode())
        return

    data = get_file_data(url)

    if data is not None:
        http_response = http_header.encode() + data
        client_socket.send(http_response)
    else:
        http_header = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n"
        error_message = "404 Not Found\nThe requested resource could not be found.\nOmer Sahar"
        http_response = http_header + error_message
        client_socket.send(http_response.encode())


def validate_http_request(request):
    if len(request_split) >= 3:
        if request_split[2] == "HTTP/1.1":
            if request_split[0] == "GET":
                return True, request_split[1]
            else:
                return False, "405"
    return False, "400"


def handle_client(client_socket):
    print('Client connected')

    while True:
        client_request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not client_request:
            break

        valid_http, resource = validate_http_request(client_request)
        if valid_http:
            print('Got a valid HTTP request')
            handle_client_request(resource, client_socket)
            break
        else:
            print('Got an invalid HTTP request')
            if resource == "405":
                http_response = "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed\nContent-Type: text/plain\nAllow: GET\n\n405 Method Not Allowed. Try another method!"
                client_socket.send(http_response.encode())
            elif resource == "400":
                http_response = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n400 Bad Request"
                client_socket.send(http_response.encode())

    print('Closing connection')
    client_socket.close()


server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen()
print("Listening for connections on port {}".format(PORT))

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print('New connection received')
    handle_client(client_socket)
```

to test this program, i sent HTTP requests using curl:
`curl http://localhost:8080/index.html`- for this i was getting 200 OK as expected.
`curl http://localhost:8080/notexist.html`- for this i was getting 404 Not Found as expected.

i can send as many GET requests as i wanted with no problem at all

but when i was sending this:
`curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/index.html`
i was expecting 405 response, but instead i got a freeze from the server side and when i stopped the server, i got the response i was expecting. same goes for 400 response.

EDIT 2 CORRECT CODE:

```py
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8080
DEFAULT_URL = "webroot/index.html"


# Utility function to get file data
def get_file_data(filename):
    if filename == DEFAULT_URL:
        filepath = DEFAULT_URL
    else:
        filepath = f"webroot/{filename}"
    try:
        with open(filepath, "rb") as file:
            return file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None


# Handle a client request
def handle_client_request(resource, client_socket):
    if resource == "/":
        url = DEFAULT_URL
    else:
        url = resource

    
    split_url = url.split('.')
    filetype = split_url[-1]
    if filetype == 'html':
        http_header = f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n"
    elif filetype == 'jpg':
        http_header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\n"
    else:
        http_header = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\nContent-Type: text/plain\n"
        error_message = "404 Not Found\nThe requested resource could not be found."
        http_response = http_header + f"Content-Length: {len(error_message)}\n\n" + error_message
        client_socket.sendall(http_response.encode())
        client_socket.close()
        return

    data = get_file_data(url)

    if data is not None:
        http_header += f"Content-Length: {len(data)}\n\n"
        http_response = http_header.encode() + data
        client_socket.sendall(http_response)
        client_socket.close()
    else:
        error_message = "404 Not Found\nThe requested resource could not be found.\nOmer Sahar"
        http_header += f"Content-Length: {len(error_message)}\n\n"
        http_response = http_header.encode() + error_message.encode()
        client_socket.sendall(http_response)
        client_socket.close()


# Validate an HTTP request
def validate_http_request(request):
    request = request.decode()
    request_split = request.split()
    if len(request_split) >= 3:
        if request_split[2] == "HTTP/1.1":
            if request_split[0] == "GET":
                return True, request_split[1]
            elif request_split[0] != "GET":
                return False, "405"
    return False, "400"


# Handle a client's request
def handle_client(client_socket):
    print('Client connected')

    while True:
        client_request = b''
        while True:
            chunk = client_socket.recv(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            client_request += chunk
            if b'\r\n\r\n' in client_request:
                break

        if not client_request:
            break

        valid_http, resource = validate_http_request(client_request)
        if valid_http:
            print('Got a valid HTTP request')
            handle_client_request(resource, client_socket)
            break
        else:
            print('Got an invalid HTTP request')
            if resource == "405":
                http_header = "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed\nContent-Type: text/plain\nAllow: GET"
                error_message = "405 Method Not Allowed. Try another method!"
                http_response = http_header + f"Content-Length: {len(error_message)}\n\n" + error_message
                client_socket.sendall(http_response.encode())
                client_socket.close()
                break
            elif resource == "400":
                http_header = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\nContent-Type: text/plain"
                error_message = "400: Bad Request"
                http_response = http_header + f"Content-Length: {len(error_message)}\n\n" + error_message
                client_socket.sendall(http_response.encode())
                client_socket.close()
                break


# Set up the server socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen()
print("Listening for connections on port {}".format(PORT))

# Accept and handle client connections
while True:
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print('New connection received')
    handle_client(client_socket)
```

Comment: You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and its successors to implement HTTP correctly. It is extremely non-trivial. There are any number of problems and missing features here. Too broad. Cancel the project and do something that hasn't already been done better.

Comment: Just to clarify, this project is only a simple school assignment, using the material that was learned in class and some Google searching if needed. It wasn't meant to be a real implementation.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The client still expects you to implement HTTP properly. It will still expect the `Content-Length` header unless you close the socket after sending the response, which is the main problem here, but there are others.

Comment: You should add more print statements at various points. This is the way. Your sample says "code stops here" but from the code you're showing, there's no way you could know if it actually stopped there or at the line before or the line after. Print any and everything that might be of interest to the program flow (including buffer contents). Then, if still not working, include the print output here.

Comment: Will also mention that `client_request = client_socket.recv(1024)` does not guarantee that you've received the entire request or *only* that request. HTTP is a text based protocol, layered over TCP, which is stream-based, and you need to demarcate request boundaries yourself by scanning for the blank line at the end. Likewise, you're assuming that `client_socket.send(xxx)` is sending the entire `xxx` but TCP doesn't guarantee that and it's a bad practice to assume it. If you want to make sure the entire buffer is sent, use `sendall`.

Comment: Your server keeps the TCP connection open after you've send the response and is waiting for another request. But in this case you would need to specify to the client where the response has ended, so that it knows when to stop waiting for more response data. This is either done by closing the connection after the response is done (which you don't) or by giving the size of the body with a Content-length header or similar (which you don't do either). Since none of this is done the client is simply waiting for more response data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments! I tried my best to write what you people suggested and it is working! I add a `Content-Length` header and closed the connection on the `handle_client_request` function and added a complete request handling. I also modified the while loop in the `handle_client` function a little and realised that i did not add `break` commands when needed.
the full correct code edited in the question(:

Comment: You need the Content- length header *or* the close.